# How to download an archive and extract it without saving the archive to disk?

Tags: shell, pipe, tar, wget

I'd like to download, and extract an archive under a given directory. Here is how I've been doing it so far:

```
wget http://downloads.mysql.com/source/dbt2-0.37.50.3.tar.gz
tar zxf dbt2-0.37.50.3.tar.gz
mv dbt2-0.37.50.3 dbt2
```

I'd like instead to download and extract the archive *on the fly*, without having the `tar.gz` written to the disk. I think this is possible by piping the output of `wget` to `tar`, and giving `tar` a target, but in practice I don't know how to put the pieces together.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You can do it by telling `wget` to output its payload to stdout (with the flag `-O-`) and suppress its own output (with the flag `-q`):

```
wget -qO- your_link_here | tar xvz
```

To specify a target directory:

```
wget -qO- your_link_here | tar xvz -C /target/directory
```

If you happen to have GNU `tar`, you can also rename the output dir:

```
wget -qO- your_link_here | tar --transform 's/^dbt2-0.37.50.3/dbt2/' -xvz
```

Comment: To specified path should be: `wget -qO- your_link_here | tar xvz - -C /target/directory`

Comment: maybe just tell people to use tar instead wget then?

Comment: `wget -qO- <url> | tar -xvz -C <target folder>` worked on gnu tar.

Comment: will this require less than double the space of the archive on my disk?
right now I'm having to unpack a huge tar and I'm looking for a way to optimize the operation space-wise

Comment: You don’t have to specify the stdin `-`.

Answer (score 42):

Another option is to use `curl` which writes to `stdout` by default:

```
curl -s -L https://example.com/archive.tar.gz | tar xvz - -C /tmp
```

Comment: I like your option more than others but ```curl -s some_url | tar xvz - -C /tmp```

Comment: as [FiftiN](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/342396/fiftin) suggested -> e.g. to view a filtered list of files inside repository one could use: `$ curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/repo_owner/repo_name/tarball | tar tvfz - -C /tmp --wildcards *.py`

Comment: Better curl with "-L" to follow redirects

Comment: works by default on a Mac too

Answer (score 13):

This oneliner does the trick:

```
tar xvzf -C /tmp/ < <(wget -q -O - http://foo.com/myfile.tar.gz)
```

short explanation:
the right side in the parenthesis is executed first (`-q` tells wget to do it quietly, `-O -` is used to write the output to stdout).

Then we create a named pipe using the process substitution operator from Bash `<(` to create a *named pipe*.
This way we create a temporary file descriptor and then direct the contents of that descriptor to tar using the `<` file redirection operator.

Comment: This would need `-f -` (for stdin) or `-f <(wget...` to work.

Comment: This should be something like 
```tar zxvf - <  <(wget -q -O - https://github.com/peak/s5cmd/releases/download/v2.1.0/s5cmd_2.1.0_Linux-64bit.tar.gz)```

Answer (score 2):

Named pipe with stdin solution and really mind the flags for tar's `-xvz`

```
tar -xvz -C /tmp/ -f <(wget -q -O - https://github.com/user/repo/release/download/v/v.tar.gz)
```

Answer (score 2):

One liner that handles redirects and can extract `tar.bz2` files. Use `xz`for extracting gzip files.

```bsh
curl -L https://downloads.getmonero.org/cli/linux64 | tar xj
```

Answer (score 0):

The extraction part should take input from `STDOUT`. We may need `tar -xzvf - -C <output_dir>`

Example:

```bash
# this may not work
# It might complain 
# tar (child): -C: Cannot open: No such file or directory
wget -qO - https://dlcdn.apache.org/spark/spark-3.3.0/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3-scala2.13.tgz | tar -xzvf -C /opt/spark --strip-component 1


# this should work. 
wget -qO - https://dlcdn.apache.org/spark/spark-3.3.0/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3-scala2.13.tgz | tar -xzvf - -C /opt/spark --strip-component 1
```

Comment: How would one go about this using the wget -N flag?  So only do this if the downloaded file has changed?  I would imagine I would need to save the existing file for that?